# Qt QNetworkAccessManager always return empty data and the status code is 0

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I met a strange problem and I have searched for several hours but cannot find solution.

I am using Qt to write a Windows desktop application and I want to download a file from the Internet so I use `QNetworkAccessManager`. Following is my test code, which is in the MainWindow's constructor:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("www.example.org"));
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
if(manager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible){
    qDebug() << "Network accessible";
}
else{
    qDebug() << "Network is not accessible";
}
manager->get(request);
connect(manager, manager->finished, this, connFinished);
```

And next is `connFinished` function:

```
void MainWindow::connFinished(QNetworkReply *r){
    int statusCode = r->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug() << statusCode;
}
```

After running the code, the output is:

```
Network accessible
0
```

I'm sure that the `www.example.org` can be accessed in my machine and there is **no redirection**. The HTTP status code is 0 even my PC has disconnected from the Internet. The problem still happens in a new project so it's not only this project's problem.

**My Qt version**: Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)

**Compiler**: gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm-1)

Is there anyone knows why this happened? Thanks!

Project files and code:

test.pro

```
QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void connFinished(QNetworkReply *r);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("www.example.org"));
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    if(manager->networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible){
        qDebug() << "Network accessible";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Network is not accessible";
    }
    manager->get(request);
    connect(manager, manager->finished, this, connFinished);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::connFinished(QNetworkReply *r){
    int statusCode = r->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug() << statusCode;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Try to handle errors...

Comment: Thank you.  I have found the problem. I have to use "http://www.example.org" rather than "www.exmaple.org"...

Answer (score 1):

Before call [QNetworkAccessManager::get()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#get) function you have to connects it signals to slot.

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("www.example.org"));    
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(connFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
manager->get(request);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have changed the code. But the result is not changed. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found where the problem is. I have to use `http://www.exmaple.org` rather than `www.example.org`, otherwise the QNAM will report a `ProtocolUnknownError` error. I assumed that the QNAM will guess the protocol type. But sadly it won't.

Answer (score 0):

If using https protocol in your URL, you should add the following dll files beside your executable file.

libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll